# Image inside text block (CSS)

Tags: html, css

can someone help me with a little trick in css? I need to put an image (`<a><img/></a>`) inside a text block (`<p></p>`) like the image above:

[image: http://img12.imageshack.us/img12/6137/f0uq.png]

Like @StephanMuller said, that's not possible, i was looking for a float:center, that doesn't exist, but i can work around with some float:left, and right! Thanks again everybody, sorry for not been so clear, please don't downvote me ! SOLVED :)

Comment: Please post the code you've tried.

Comment: Apologies, my Latin is not so good... Are the images simply plonked over the top of words, or are they in between words?

Comment: @gvee probably plonked over the top of words, since you can see next to "tris" a little black "dot"

Comment: Not sure whether this is possible in HTML at all. It would be news to me. You can float an image to the left hand or right hand corner but that's pretty much it

Comment: I am very curious now. Did one of the answers work?

Comment: If the text has to be under the images, just do `img{position: absolute}` otherwise, if you want it around the images, there's currently no solution, even with pretty ugly hacks I think. In the future, there might be workarounds. See [CSS exclusions](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-exclusions/) or [CCC shapes](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-shapes-1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible with a simple html/css construction. You're looking for  `float:center`-like behavior, which unfortunately doesn't exist.

The main problem here is that images inside text are inline (or inline-block) elements per definition (if you make it a block it breaks up the flow of the text). This in it's turn means that other lines of text are not aware of where the image is. `float` was deviced to solve this, but it only works on the left and right side of something, not in the middle.

The closest I could get was this: http://jsfiddle.net/5HPMq/

As you can see, I hardcoded some heights to be able to easily set the right negative margins on the images. This way the height of the image doesn't influence the line-height of the rest of the line, but as I stated the other lines are not aware of where the image is, so they will flow behind it.

TL;DR: Sorry, you can't do this.

*addition*

I was assuming you want the text to flow around tie image. If you merely want to overlap the images on the lines above and below it, use my jsfiddle and see if you can work from there.

Comment: This answer should not have been downvoted. Anyway, in the futur, there might be workarounds with `shape-outside` but we'll have to wait...

Comment: I can't wait until that happens, but as so many upcoming features it's probably going to be years until the support is good enough to *actually* use it. In the meantime we wait :P

Comment: @loko I didn't downvoted anything. I just said your solution could be simplified.

Comment: @StephanMuller Thanks a lot! Your jsfiddle have shown me that this is actually impossible, it was exactly that what i wanted, but there are some ways to make it pretty! I modified your example, and you know some way to make the text follow the first image, aligned to the left? http://jsfiddle.net/5HPMq/ I don't have enough reputation to upvote you, but you helped me the most!

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want the image just in front of your text.

This might help:

```
<img style="position:absolute; TOP:100px; LEFT:100px; WIDTH:50px; HEIGHT:50px" SRC="image.jpg">
```

top:100px; and left:50px; are the starting points. Just find out the coordinates.

tried it myself and it looks like this for me:

[image]

Comment: In this case, a simple `img {
    position: absolute;
}` would do it far better since it keeps the image exactly where it should be in the text

Comment: @Brewal Doesn't this work? If it doesn't then I dont get what he wants.

Comment: Thanks dude! But that was not what i wanted, i don't wanted  the image over the text, i wanted the text around the image, like an MS Word document!

Comment: @WilliamCastro Aha I have no idea how to do that, goodluck with that! Of course you could just add enough space between the words where you want the image to come so the image just covers the spaces, but that's an ugly solution of course.

Comment: Yeah, i think it's actually not possible right now! And put some spaces will make it worse hehehe!But thanks again for your help! ;)